# Using templates for multiple pages in meteor

Tags: html, meteor

I was working on a web app prior to finding meteor and to have multiple pages I had things like this (I'm using bootstrap):

`<a href="../signUp.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">signup</a>`

In order to have a button for a user to sign up. I'm trying to convert this to a template in order to work with the meteor framework. I made a template that had all the code from my signUp.html file and changed that line of code to look like this:

`<a href={{> signUp}} class="btn btn-lg btn-default">signup</a>`

and this gave me the following error:

`INCLUSION template tag is not allowed in an HTML attribute`

I changed it again to be like this:

`<a {{> signUp}} class="btn btn-lg btn-default">signup</a>`

and I got this error:

`Reactive HTML attributes must either have a constant
   name or consist of a single {{helper}} providing a dictionary of names and
   values.  A template tag of type INCLUSION is not allowed here.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need is a router. Check out [iron router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router)
You can add it using

```
meteor add iron:router
```

Then, set up the routes for your signup page. (Assuming that you have named the template as "signUp" )

```
Router.route('/signup', function () {
   this.render('signUp');
});
```

And finally use the link as :

```
<a href="/signup" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">signup</a>
```